# C# function by passing parameters

Tags: c#, .net

Calculate a c# function by passing parameters

My function is something like this:

```
Result<double> Evaluate(string var, Result<double> height, Result<double> perm)
```

Var can be anything user wants to enter. 
For example, if the user enters Depth,
then the calculation would be like height * perm and return the var.
If user enters SC the calculation is height/ perm and result is stored in var and returns the result

I tried something like this:

```
List<double> calvar = new List<double>
Switch(var){
    Case “depth”:
        calvar = height * perm
        return calvar
}
```

I got an error saying * cannot be used for operators of type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment I don't understand your question. Could you try to clarify it, ideally showing how far you've got and where you're stuck? See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for some suggestions for improving your question.

Comment: We usually avoid writing code so that unrelated things are done inside one method. It makes that method unnecessarily complicated. If you want a method for depth, write that. If you want one for SC, write that. Then instead of having an argument that says what you want to do, you indicate what you want to do by calling that specific function.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error, because you're trying to multiply to objects of the type Result and not the double values itself.
If you want to use the * operator for objects of the type Result you have to overload the * operator in your class.

```
public class Result<T>
{
  public T Value { get; set; }

  public static Result<T> operator * (Result<T> a, Result<T> b)
  {
    // Multiply Logic
  }
}
```